# viewer for data.las using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to ask is there any viewer free for data .las using HTML and javascript?
because i want to display data .las .ascii and .log

many thanks

Comment: What is a `.las` file?

Comment: A LAS file is an industry-standard binary format for storing airborne lidar data. The LAS dataset allows you to examine LAS files, in their native format, quickly and easily, providing detailed statistics and area coverage of the lidar data contained in the LAS files. some kind like that

Comment: Check https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77427/viewing-lidar-data-from-web-browser